# Snap back feel when element becomes fixed

Tags: jquery, css

Forgive me if this answer already exists, but I haven't been able to find an answer (maybe due to lack of terminology knowledge?)

When I scroll on my page, I have 3 elements that will become fixed if they reach a certain point. I'm trying to make it so that it has more of a natural feel though, so they would go a bit past the point, but have that elastic-y feel and go back into position.

So right now I have:

```
var jq = jQuery;
jq(window).scroll(function(){
var scroll = jq(window).scrollTop();
   if(scroll >= 508){
       jq(".butterflies").addClass('stay');
   }else{
       jq(".butterflies").removeClass('stay');
   }
});

.stay{position:absolute;top:1100px;}
```

The jq variable is because it's in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Was a bit unclear about your code and your description of the desired result, but I think I can see where you're going with this. One way you can do this is by creating a tiny jQuery function to do the animating of position.

However, I'm going to suggest a simpler solution avoiding extra javascript and simply using CSS transitions. CSS transitions can't be applied to `position` so you must add a wrapper around your "butterflies" and then you will be able to animate the `top` and `left` positions. You can play with the timing in seconds or milliseconds to adjust the "snap back" feel.

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/zKCNy/

Comment: I was thinking something similar.. basically detecting when the scroll stops, and then transition it back to the absolute position.